# How do I write a for loop in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Why does the following code loop 5000 times instead of the 5 times I expect?

```
int height = 5;

for (int height; height > 0; height -= 1){
    printf('Something')  }
}
```

Comment: Just remove the in-loop declaration altogether:  `for (; height > 0; height--)` will work.

Comment: @TomKarzes; In some context you may need to retain the value of  `height` in the outer scope. In that case you have to use another variable for looping.

Comment: answer: *You don't.* Understanding the basic syntax and clauses of `for` would make this clear. Also, it's more idiomatic and readable to write `--height` instead of `height -= 1`. _[insert obligatory OT rant about not using post inc/decrement unless you need them]_

Comment: Some questions like these have 10 downvotes in a minute. Others have an answer with (currently) three upvotes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but when I run it, it does not iterate through the loop 5 times but rather something like 5000.

That's because `height` declared in the `for` loop [*shadows*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the one declared outside. So you are
effectively using uninitialized `height`, which is [potentially undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11962457/4389800).

You can leave out the declaration in order to use the previously declared value:

```
int height = 5;

for (; height > 0; height -= 1) {
    printf("Something");
}
```

If you don't want to change `height`, you can use a temporary:

```
int height = 5;

for (int x = height; x > 0; x -= 1) {
    printf("Something");
}
```

which would leave `height` unchanged.

Also note that values in single quotes are multi-byte chars and are not strings. So you can't pass `'Something'` to `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do you have to redefine variables in a for loop in C

That may be because of the fact that you want to preserve/use the value of variable after the loop.

In case of

```
int height = 5;

for (int h = height; h > 0; h--){
    printf('Something')  }
}
```

`height` will have value `5`. While in case of

```
int height = 5;

for (height; height > 0; height--){
    printf('Something')  }
}
```

`height` will have value zero after the `for` loop.

Comment: Of course, the `height` in the first `for` clause there doesn't achieve anything, and may make readers of your code think you meant to do something else. IMO it's better to omit it.

Comment: @underscore_d; Apart from that there were few other bugs int the earlier code snippets. I have fixed all after multiple edits :)

Comment: Oh, I mean the `for (height;` that's now in the final excerpt - not sure why I said "first" - but I see what you mean about the other ones. :P

Comment: @TonyTannous; I guess there is a check in `for` loop which ensures that `height` must not go below `0`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what redefining originally was.

Basically, because C have scopes, redefining a variable hides all variables from outer scopes:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        // Code that'll be looped 100 times
        // Code here can't access the outer `i`
    }
```

If you don't redefine it

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    for (; i<10; i++)
        // Code that'll be looped 10 times
    // Code that'll be run only once
}
```

If you define a variable without initializing it:

```
for (int h; h>0; h--)
    // Code that'll be looped for unknown times
```

In this code, the initial value of `h` is **indeterminate**. It could be 5000 or zero, or even more than 2,000,000,000! Always assign a value to a variable before using it.

Comment: @user694733 My bad. While editing I got dizzy.

Answer (score -1):

You have to redefine `height` variable with user input in your loop definition.

You can do it like this:

```
int user_input;
scanf("%d", &user_input);

for (int height = user_input; height > 0; height -= 1){
    printf("height = %d\n", height);  
}
```

If user enters "5", this code will print this:

```
height = 5
height = 4
height = 3
height = 2
height = 1
```

Comment: Oops, of course. Still, I presume they already know how to do that, and it wasn't the main thing they were asking about. You don't really answer the question about redefining or reusing the variable, *once* the user has supplied it. Saying _"You have to redefine"_ isn't true, as everyone else has shown.

Comment: "I want to get the variable as input from the user." - author of the question said about user input. I just wrote an example with user input.

Comment: "I presume they already know how to do that" - i wrote my answer when it was no other answers. Further i edited it and it changed position in answers list. I am new here, sorry.